# Не компилируется игра в юнити 2021.3.4f1

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, mono

Пробую скомпилировать игру в юнити на андроид и оно не компилируется

20 варнингов и 5 ошибок компиляции

1 ошибка:

```
Note: D:\hvss\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Вторая ошибка:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

3 ошибка:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\hvss\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\hvss\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

4 ошибка:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

5 ошибка:

```
    Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 254 seconds (253685 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`
```

Что делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю проблема с хранилищем ключей судя по строке

```
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

Проверьте и заполните ключи подписи в Player Settings, они должны быть заполнены

Чтобы заполнить их необходимо создать или воспользоваться хранилищем через Keystore Manager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, заработало